# How can I setup my route tables to allow traffic in my VPC between my webserver in a public subnet to the database server in the private subnet?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

My IP range is 10.60.0.0/16.  I already have a route setup for 10.60.0.0/16 - Local.  All my ACLs and Security groups are fully open.   I do have a NAT instance setup so that the private subnet instances can see the internet.

Update:
The only way I have been able to get it to work so far is to launch a ENI into the private subnet and attach it to the server in the public subnet.  It seems to work this way but is suboptimal.

Comment: That really should be working (as you doubtless have concluded, too)... both instances have working default routes in their internal route tables and nothing like iptables in the way? At the risk of asking the obvious, does a traceroute from public node to private node... and private to public... indicate an unexpected outbound path (specifically the public node's traceroute to the private node going out toward the Internet instead of inward)?

Answer (score 1):

in a vpc, in order for an instance to be publicly accesible, you must associate a public elastic ip.  additionally, the security group associated with the instance must permit traffic.   so for a webserver, this may look like

> ec2-authorize [sec-group-id] -P tcp -p 80 -s 0.0.0.0/0

another way to do this, and keep the instances private (ie. no incoming connections to them directly from internet) is by setting up an elb, and associating instances with it

Comment: This is correct. But - you really should switch over to the new [awscli](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). Not only is it **much** faster, but it's also much more consistent and it provides access to all of the AWS APIs in a single tool.

Comment: old school ec2 api command line tools get the job done..... and are easy to script...... i will look at awscli, but the original still is best imho

Comment: Ok, but that still does not answer my question.  My SG and ACL are set to allow ALL 0.0.0.0/0 in and out.  My instance is in a public subnet but cannot see the instance in the private subnet (same zone)

Comment: My webserver is already publicly accessible, I am asking how it can access the private subnet server.

Comment: unless you've messed with the main routing table, you should have DEFAULT access from ANY instance to any OTHER instance in the same VPC. Doesn't matter if either is in public or private subnets. Now, if your DATABASE, or your instance networking rules don't allow it, or the security groups that one or the other is currently assigned doesn't allow the packets in from the other . . .well . . . You get the idea. You can test this by spinning up an a pub and pvt instances, making sure their security group has port 22 open. log into the pub one and ssh to the private one. It will work.